# cx_Freeze: ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, windows, importerror, cx-freeze, pyqt5

I've successfully created a standalone version of my Python 3.3 program with cx_Freeze 4.3.1 and it works perfectly on one PC but raises an error on another. The last line of the error says:

```
File "ExtensionLoader_PyQt5_QtWidgets.py", line 11, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Both PCs do not have Python installed and are running 64bit Windows 7, so I really don't know what could cause the error.

**Solution**: With the Dependency Walker I could determine that the missing DLL was "D3DCompiler_43.dll". So a DirectX Update should solve the error.

Comment: Try to open your file with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). It may be able to pinpoint which DLL is missing.